# jQuery click event is affecting all tags with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I'm working with `node-horseman` and I'm making use of `.evaluate()` and jQuery to trigger a `click` function on a button on Google Alerts. It's working, but it's affecting all `.delete_button`.

Each `li` has a `data-id` attribute that has an unique value. It's created by Google Alerts itself, so I took advantage of this to select the correct block with `node-horseman`, and by testing with `.html()`, it works nicely, it does select the right block by the given `data-id`.

```
jQuery('#manage-alerts-div li').attr('data-id', this.feedID).find('.alert_buttons').html()
```

The inspected code of the Alert based on the given `data-id` is the following:

[image]

And the returned HTML with the jQuery selection:

> ```
> <a href="/alerts/feeds/07997923364799863317/3782479325533077987" tabindex="0"><span class="rss_icon" title="RSS"></span></a><span class="edit_button alert_button" title="Edit" role="button" tabindex="0"></span><span class="delete_button alert_button" title="Delete" role="button" tabindex="0"></span>
> ```

Then, I try to click on the `.delete_button`:

```
jQuery('#manage-alerts-div li').attr('data-id', this.feedID).find('.alert_buttons > .delete_button').trigger('click')
```

But it insists on affect ALL the present `.delete_button` class.

Comment: What does `jQuery('#manage-alerts-div li').attr('data-id', this.feedID).find('.alert_buttons').length` give you? The `.html()` method only returns the html from the *first* element in the list returned by `.find()`, so that wouldn't make it clear whether you've accidentally selected multiple elements..

Comment: What's the code for the `click` that you're triggering?

Comment: @nnnnnn It gives me `2`, the exact expected number. I do have two alerts.

Comment: @jonmrich I do not follow.

Comment: Why are you calling the `.attr()` method? That is *setting* the value for all `'#manage-alerts-div li'` elements, not selecting the ones that have that attribute.

Comment: This `('.alert_buttons > .delete_button').trigger('click')` means that you're essentially clicking the object with the class `.delete_button`. Somewhere there has to be code that says what to do when you click `.delete_button`.

Comment: @nnnnnn I expected to select the `li` that has the specified `data-id` attribute. I thought it worked because the `console.log()` did show the correct block, as shown in the question. How do I proceed to select the `li` that has that `data-id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to select only the element with a specific attribute value, try the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) as follows:

```
jQuery('#manage-alerts-div li[data-id="' + this.feedID + '"]')
  .find('.alert_buttons > .delete_button')
  .trigger('click');
```

Here's a breakdown of what your existing code does:

```
jQuery('#manage-alerts-div li')
```

...selects all li elements in `#manager-alerts-div`, then

```
.attr('data-id', this.feedID)
```

...*sets* their `data-id` attribute to whatever `this.feedID` is, then

```
.find('.alert_buttons > .delete_button')
```

...finds elements within the original set of all `'#manage-alerts-div li'` elements, then

```
.trigger('click')
```

...triggers the click handler on all of them.

The testing with `.html()` that you mentioned may have confused things because `.html()` returns the content of only the first element in the jQuery object, even if the selector you had used matched many elements, so that might have made it seem like you'd selected only one element.

Comment: I'm testing it with `jQuery('#manage-alerts-div li[data-id="' + this.feedID + '"]').html()` but it returns `undefined`...

Comment: Ok. Tested by logging out `'#manage-alerts-div li[data-id="' + this.feedID + '"]'` and it turns out that somehow, how the `this.feedID` is `undefined`.

Comment: So `console.log(this.feedID)` is `undefined`? If so that has nothing to do with my code, but I don't know what else to tell you because you haven't explained where `this.feedID` is coming from. (Or supposed to be coming from.) What is `this`? You'd need to show the surrounding code.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I did not explain, that'd take long. But your answer is correct, I hard coded the `data-id` and worked, so I will mark as correct one. Thank you.